# TypeScript Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am getting this awful error when I run this typescript... It says I am passing in the wrong 'type' of argument... This is my first time using typescript, any help would be appreciated.

Here is the error:

```
Could not apply type 'number' to argument 1 which is of type 'HTMLElement'.
```

And here is my TS code:

```
class Offer {
    quantity: number;
    price: number;
    client: string;

    constructor (quantity: number, price: number, client: string) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.client = name;
    }

    getSelectedItem() {
        var option = $('#ddown :selected').text();
    }


}

class Bid {
    quantity: number;
    price: number;
    client: string;

    constructor (quantity: number, price: number, client: string) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.client = name;
    }

    getSelectedItem() {
        var option = $('#ddown :selected').text();
    }


}

function getBid() {
    var x = document.getElementById("quantity");
    var y = document.getElementById("price");
    console.log(y);
    var n = document.getElementById("name");

    return new Bid(x, y, n);

    // $("<tr><td>" + n.value + "</td><td>" + x.value + "X$" + y.value + "</td></tr>").appendTo("#table");
}

function getOffer() {
    var x = document.getElementById("quantity");
    var y = document.getElementById("price");
    console.log(y);
    var n = document.getElementById("name");

    return new Offer(x, y, n);

    // $("<tr><td>" + n.value + "</td><td></td><td>" + x.value + "X$" + y.value + "</td></tr>").appendTo("#table");


}

function append_bid(bid) {
    alert("efff you");
    $("<tr><td>" + bid.client + "</td><td>" + bid.quantity + "X$" + bid.price+ "</td></tr>").appendTo("#table");
}

function append_offer(offer) {
    $("<tr><td>" + offer.client + "</td><td></td><td>" + offer.quantity + "X$" + offer.price + "</td></tr>").appendTo("#table");
}

var bids = [];
var offers = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var msg = $("#ddown option:selected").text();

        if (msg == 'Bid'){
                bids.push(getBid());
                alert(bids.peek);
                append_bid(bids.peek);
                console.log('here');
                return false;
            } else {
                offers.push(getOffer());
                console.log('whatever');
                console.log(offers[0].price);
                append_offer(offers.peek);
            }
            return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

I suppose some HTML wouldn't hurt either...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Make Dem Trades Boi</title>
</head>
<body>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="class.js"></script>



    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>bids</th>
            <th>offers</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <select id="ddown">
    <option selected="selected" value="bid">Bid</option>
    <option value="offer">Offer</option>
  </select>

    <form id="form">
        Quantity:<input id="quantity" type="number"><br>
        Price:<input id="price" type="number"><br>
        Name:<input id="name" type="string">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Buy">
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: I think you need to do some `parse` to change the `type` within your code

Answer (score 4):

In `getOffer()`, here:

```
return new Offer(x, y, n);
```

`x` is an element (and so are `y` and `n`). If you want `x`’s value as a `Number`, you can use `+x.value` (or `Number(x.value)`, if you like to be explicit).

Comment: Which, of course, the function signature `quantity: number, price: number, client: string` rejects.

Comment: Well I changed it to this: return new Bid(x.value, y.value, n.value);  and it still won't work

Comment: @minitech what do you mean?

Comment: @m.sherman: Use `+x.value`, not `x.value`. `+` casts to `Number`. See the text of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor on `Bid` takes a number, another number and a string:

```
constructor (quantity: number, price: number, client: string)
```

You are passing a `HTMLElement` to each of these. To satisfy the types of the `Bid` constrcutor, you need to get the data out of each element and parse it, which is reasonably easy to do...

```
var x = +(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("quantity")).value;
var y = +(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("price")).value;
var n = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("name")).value;

return new Bid(x, y, n);
```

To break this answer down, you need to tell the compiler that the `HTMLElement` is in fact a `HTMLInputElement` and use the `+` operator to [slacker parse](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201402/Blog/Slacker-Parsing-In-JavaScript/) the two numbers.

If you don't like the shorthand `+` operation, you can use:

```
var x = parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("quantity")).value, 10);
var y = parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("price")).value, 10);
var n = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("name")).value;

return new Bid(x, y, n);
```